# Vaadin Lumo custom button theming

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin Flow 23 and want to apply some custom styling to `Button` (`<vaadin-button>`) elements.

I've added a file `/frontend/component-styles/button.css` where I apply some styles directly to the button itself (no specific theme variant or state):

```
:host {
    border: 1px solid #AEB136;
}
```

I've included this by adding `@CssImport` to a java class like this:

```
@CssImport(value = "./component-styles/button.css", themeFor = "vaadin-button")
```

The problem is that this style is not only applied to `<vaadin-button>` elements, but also to `<vaadin-menu-bar>` elements, or more precisely the `<vaadin-menu-bar-button>` elements they contain.  This does not seem to be the case if I specify a particular theme variant or `:hover` or `[active]` state.

Do I need to do anything special to make sure `:host { }` styles are applied to `<vaadin-button>` only and not to `<vaadin-menu-bar-button>`?

**Update**

I've noticed I can use `:host(vaadin-button) { }` to have it applied only to `<vaadin-button>`, but I thought `themeFor = "vaadin-button"` would take care of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu bar button is [extending](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/master/packages/menu-bar/src/vaadin-menu-bar-button.js) the button component and therefore also his styles.

If you only wanna style the button you can also use `vaadin-button` as selector in your global `styles.css`.

Answer (score 3):

`themeFor` specifies into which component the css should be injected, but it does not prevent style inheritance to subclasses of that component.